# Nvarchar and text are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, guid, nvarchar

With SQL Server 2008, I'd like to add a variable (`@wfID`) into a text, like below:

```
 DECLARE @wfID uniqueidentifier
 SET @wfID = NEWID()

'<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; " />  <br><input type="button"
    value="" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://localhost/TestWeb2/Test_Look.aspx?Test_ID='
    + convert(nvarchar, @wfID)
    + '&quot;);" /></br>',
```

So, I'd like to add the `@wfID` to the text but it always says

> The data types nvarchar and text are incompatible in the add operator.

I tried converting everything into nvarchar, but then I got this:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your call to **convert** you try to convert to just **nvarchar** which implicitly means **nvarchar(1)**, i.e. there is not room for the whole guid to be converted.

Change that to

```
convert(nvarchar(36), @wfID)
```

and it will work.

For some strange reason MSSQL gives an arithmetic overflow if doing `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,NEWID())` but gives a proper 'Insufficient result space' if doing `SELECT CONVERT(varchar,NEWID())`.

Comment: Excellent. Works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine'

```
    --EXECUTE usp_TEST
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TEST](

    @UserID nvarchar(max) ='82F1A3A6-4DC6-481F-9046-856270E66468'
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    declare @sqlwhere1 nvarchar(max)=''
    SELECT   @sqlwhere1= 'SELECT * 
        FROM [yourtablename] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE '

        IF(@UserID <> '')
        BEGIN 
         SELECT @sqlwhere1=@sqlwhere1 +' convert(nvarchar(max),UserId)= '''+convert(nvarchar(max),@UserID)+'''' 
        END 

    EXECUTE (@sqlwhere1) 

    END
```